# AngularJS, UIRouter – Transclude HTML into ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I wanted to pass some `HTML` into an `ui-view`, much like you would do with a normal directive. However, I can't seem to understand if `ui-view` supports it or not. I'm doing this, currently:

```
<div ui-view
     class='my-class'>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

And in one of my directive's template (**EDIT: actually, it's the "state's template"**), I am doing:

```
<section class="other-class container">
    <form ng-cloak novalidate>
        <div> Stuff </div>
    </form>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</section>
```

When running the app I get the error:
`Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <ng-transclude>`

So, does this mean that `ui-view` doesn't support `ngTransclude`? Or do I need to enable some flag in a state's `config`, like a directive's `transclude : true`?

Comment: Does your directive have transclude: true? Are you expecting the ui-view template to appear inside your directive template?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the point of putting something in ui-view, since it will be removed and replaced by the view of the current state? Do you understand what ui-view is for? The error is clear: your directive doesn't have anything to transclude, so ng-transclude inside its template doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ShaunScovil I'm sorry, I made a mistake. What I called `my-directive`'s template was actually a uiRouter state's template

Comment: @JBNizet please see the edit. Does it make sense now? I wanted to transclude the HTML into an `uiRouter` state

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do. Put your directive in the view template, not inside the ui-view tag.

Comment: @ShaunScovil ok, I never thought of that... Thanks

Comment: Can I have something like this : `<div ui-view>Hey there</div>`

Comment: @SohanShirodkar as JBNizet said, I don't think you can...